# Найти все симлинки, которые ссылаются на определенный путь

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Необходимо в директории `/home` и ее подкаталогах найти все симлинки, которые ссылаются, например, на `/home/admin/123.txt`.

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: `man find` читать доки

Comment: @AlexeyTen это вы, конечно, знатно поглумились. Зачот.

Comment: @PakUula, а в чем глумление то проявляется?

Comment: @AlexeyTen `man find` - это один из самых больших мануалов, которые есть на свете. Может быть, самый большой. 23 страницы A4. Когда я вижу отсылку к нему, мне так и хочется вспомнить старый добрый анекдот "Ты не умничай, ты пальцем ткни". Если бы вы хотя бы подсказали, какие разделы и какие опции читать, например перечислили `-L`, `-samefile`, `-xtype`. Но вы же отправили читать весь мануал со всеми 80-ю опциями командной строки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find -L /home -samefile /home/admin/123.txt -xtype l`

[Опция `-L`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Symbolic-Links) предписывает переходить по симлинкам.

Предикат `-samefile` при наличии опции `-L` срабатывает для [символических ссылок, ведущих на заданный файл](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#:%7E:text=on%20needless%20searching.-,If%20the%20%E2%80%98-L%E2%80%99%20option%20is%20in%20effect%2C,-then%20dereferencing%20of).

`-xtype l` ограничивает поиск только символическими ссылками - сам файл `/home/admin/123.txt` и хардлинки на него (если есть) в результаты поиска не попадут.

Comment: благодарю. работает!